# ASP .NET WebService Error: File not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP .NET Web service and I am getting "File Not Found" Error.

I should be able to access it through:

```
http://www.example.com/_vti_bin/AjaxUtilsWebService.asmx
```

but I am redirected to this page:

[image]

I can access any other file within the `_vti_bin`/ path, but this one.

Here is the code I have in the `AjaxUtilsWebService.asmx` file:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="MyNameSpace.AjaxUtilsWebService.AjaxUtilsWebService, MyNameSpace.AjaxUtilsWebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=d6c7fad93f418837" %>
```

And this is how my IIS manager looks like:
[image]

I can put any file in there and I am able to access it through the browser, but not this one. Also, I am able to access the other `asmx` files in the same path.

Any ideas?

The file permissions are set to "`Everyone`".

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the page you are accessing is not running into any exceptions? Have debugged the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the problem: when I built and deployed the `wsp` it apparently did not deploy the `dll` for the project the service runs on. Simply copying the generated .`dll` from the `/bin/debug` folder to `C:\Windows\assembly` and restarting `IIS` solved the issue.